# Pandas: How to group by and sum MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a dataframe with categorical attributes where the index contains duplicates. I am trying to find the sum of each possible combination of index and attribute.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,3,3],'y':[3,3,5,5]},index=[11,11,12,12])
y = x.stack()
print(y)
print(y.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())
```

output

```
11  x    1
    y    3
    x    1
    y    3
12  x    3
    y    5
    x    3
    y    5
dtype: int64
11  x    1
    y    3
    x    1
    y    3
12  x    3
    y    5
    x    3
    y    5
dtype: int64
```

The stack and group by sum are just the same.

However, the one I expect is

```
11  x    2
11  y    6
12  x    6
12  y    10
```

EDIT 2:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,3,3],'y':[3,3,5,5]},index=[11,11,12,12])
y = x.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
print(y.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())
```

output:

```
11  x    1
    y    3
    x    1
    y    3
12  x    3
    y    5
    x    3
    y    5
dtype: int64
```

EDIT3:
An issue has been logged
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10417

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With pandas 0.16.2 and Python 3, I was able to get the correct result via:

```
x.stack().reset_index().groupby(['level_0','level_1']).sum()
```

Which produces:

```
                    0
level_0 level_1 
     11       x     2
              y     6
     12       x     6
              y     10
```

You can then change the index and column names to more desirable ones using `reindex()` and `columns`.

Based on my research, I agree that the failure of the original approach appears to be a bug. I think the bug is on `Series`, which is what `x.stack()` produces. My workaround is to turn the `Series` into a `DataFrame` via `reset_index()`. In this case the `DataFrame` does not have a `MultiIndex` anymore - I'm just grouping on labeled columns.

To make sure that grouping and summing works on a `DataFrame` with a `MultiIndex`, you can try this to get the same correct output:

```
x.stack().reset_index().set_index(['level_0','level_1'],drop=True).\
groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
```

Either of these workarounds should take care of things until the bug is resolved.

I wonder if the bug has something to do with the `MultiIndex` instances that are created on a `Series` vs. a `DataFrame`. For example:

```
In[1]: obj = x.stack()
       type(obj)
Out[1]: pandas.core.series.Series

In[2]: obj.index
Out[2]: MultiIndex(levels=[[11, 11, 12, 12], ['x', 'y']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

vs.

```
In[3]: obj = x.stack().reset_index().set_index(['level_0','level_1'],drop=True)
       type(obj)
Out[3]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

In[4]: obj.index
Out[4]: MultiIndex(levels=[[11, 12], ['x', 'y']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['level_0', 'level_1'])
```

Notice how the `MultiIndex` on the `DataFrame` describes the levels more correctly.

Comment: You are a real hero.. That was pretty detail and helpful. Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help!  You are the hero, for filing the bug. I just checked its status and it looks like it was acknowledged and targeted for the 0.17.0 release. They even posted a workaround similar to mine :-)  Anyway thanks for posting it and for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`sum` allows you to specify the levels to sum over in a MultiIndex data frame.

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,3,3],'y':[3,3,5,5]},index=[11,11,12,12])
y = x.stack()

y.sum(level=[0,1])

11  x     2
    y     6
12  x     6
    y    10
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Pandas 0.15.2, you just need one more iteration of groupby

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,1,3,3],'y':[3,3,5,5]},index=[11,11,12,12])
y = x.stack().groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
print(y.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum())
```

prints

```
11  x     2
    y     6
12  x     6
    y    10
```

Comment: what version of pandas you are on? I am on 0.16.2 and python 3. for the same code I get a different output. check edit2 in question

Comment: ah... I'm on 0.15.2 - also python3.

Comment: great we have found a bug !!

Comment: but still I dont understand the reasoning behind one more groupby. If you just check the stack() ouput it is same as the first group by output.